# Where not exists with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How do I write a NHibernate criteria matching that query?

```
select * from InventoryItems i
where not exists (select inventory_id from InventoryItemCategories c where i.id = c.inventory_id and c.Category_Id = '805cec1e-1d7b-4062-9427-a26d010f4fb3')
```

I have written this, but not exists takes only one argument!

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =
   DetachedCriteria.For(typeof (InventoryItemCategories))
        .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Catgory_Id"));

var criteria=Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(InventoryItem)).
Add(Subqueries.NotExists(inventoryCategoryId,detachedCriteria));
```

Thanks a lot for the help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use aliases, nicknames to get outer table in the subquery scope. So, if we will (later) name the criteria `"myAlias"`, we can extend the subQuery defintion this way:

```
var detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<InventoryItemCategories>()
    // here we have to use the C# property names instead of the column names
    .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("InventoryId"  // local table c, col inventory_id
                               , "myAlias.ID")) // outer table i, col id
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CategoryId"           // local table c, col Category_Id   
                               , myGuid))       // the parameter passed alá '805ce...
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Catgory_Id"));
```

And adjusted criteria:

```
// outer table nickname "myAlias" here 
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<InventoryItem>("myAlias"); 
criteria.Add(Subqueries.NotExists(detachedCriteria ));
```